# ReferenceError: NODE_ENV is not defined with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

This is my index.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var compression = require('compression');
var path = require('path');

app.use(compression());
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 9000));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.set('views', __dirname + '/');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

And these are my NPM scripts for building and starting the server:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node index.js",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --progress --bail --open",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --colors"
},
```

I don't know how but I still get `ReferenceError: NODE_ENV is not defined`. Can anyone help?

Comment: Where do you use `NODE_ENV` in your JavaScript code? (The code you've posted doesn't seem to me to be the relevant code.)

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using OS X Also whan i'm using webpack server there is no problem with that... I think this is not a problem with code it self.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV
```

instead of:

```
NODE_ENV
```

When you get the error:

```
ReferenceError: NODE_ENV is not defined
```

that means that you were trying to access it like it was a variable in scope and not a property on the `process.env` object as it is.

Comment: where, how? in the index.js i assume ... I've tried this also but had the same issue :(

Comment: @Lukas I don't know where. Certainly not in the code that you provided because you didn't include anything with `NODE_ENV`

Comment: everywhere i have to in webpack config (using it to build app) i'm using process.env.NODE_ENV

Answer (score 0):

It works on Mac.

What OS you used ? If you are Windows, maybe you need checkout [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

Then change your package.json like this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config build/webpack.config.js"
  }
}
```